# Excel: How to show rank increment with + & - sign?

Tags: excel

I am preparing a keyword ranking excel sheet.

To show rank change i am using simple subtraction i.e. 94 (previous ranking) - 74 (current ranking) = 20 (improvement).

Issue 1: Because the ranking has gone up i need to show +20.

Issue 2: for keyword that was not having ranking i am using 0.

0 (no ranking) - 54 (current ranking) = -54

how to show +54?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
=IF(A1<>0,A1-B1,B1)
```

[image]

***EDIT : 1***

```
=TEXT(IF(A1<>0,A1-B1,B1),"+0;-0;0")
```

See image for reference.

[image]

***EDIT 2 :***

```
=IF(AND(A2<>0,B2<>0),TEXT(A2-B2,"+0;-0;0"),IF(A2=0,"+" & B2,"-" & A2))
```

***Conditional Formatting:***

You'll have to create two conditional formatting rules for `Column C`.

For negative numbers - `=LEFT(C1,1)="-"`
For positive numbers - `=LEFT(C1,1)="+"`

***Follow following steps:***

- Select `Column C`
- Click the Home tab and from the Conditional Formatting drop down (in the Styles group), choose New Rule
- Choose the `Use A Formula To Determine Which Cells To Format` option from the upper pane
- Enter `=LEFT(C1,1)="+"` in formula box (This is for positive numbers)
- Click Format and then click the Fill tab
- Choose a color from the palette (Choose green as you mentioned in comments)
- Click OK twice

Repeat same steps for negative numbers except that the formula should be `=LEFT(C1,1)="-"` and in formatting select red color.

Comment: great. working. but, can i assume can't show + sign for increment?

Comment: worked. accepted answer. But not 'conditional formatting' for 'highlighting cells' is not working.

Comment: @user6601842 - You didn't mention anything about conditional formatting in question. What result you want to highlight?

Comment: + with green and - with red. Also if previous ranking was 60 and current ranking is 0 so that should be -60 drop. But your solution shows +60

Comment: @user6601842 - I've added steps for conditional formatting just in case you may need.

Comment: worked. Also added third rule for 0 and gray color with =LEFT(C1,1)="0"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following table:

`Previous | Current
 94       | 74
  0       | 54
 74       | 94`

and put `=IF(A2=0;CONCATENATE("+ ";B2);CONCATENATE(IF(A2-B2>0;"+ ";"- ");ABS(A2-B2)))` into column C, than your result will be:

`Previous | Current | Rank
 94       | 74      | + 20
  0       | 54      | + 54
 74       | 94      | - 20`

Comment: my first cell is B3 and second cell is C3 and result is in D3. and this formula gives me error =IF(B3=0;CONCATENATE("+ ";C3);CONCATENATE(IF(B3-C3>0;"+ ";"- ");ABS(B3-C3)))

Comment: I guess this depends on your regional settings. Most likely Excel is complaining about the `;`. Try `=IF(B3=0,CONCATENATE("+ ",C3),CONCATENATE(IF(B3-C3>0,"+ ","- "),ABS(B3-C3)))` instead.